# Are there any guides on configuring ASP.NET Trust levels on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008, trust

I am looking for either a best practice, supported, guide from Microsoft or a bloggers/developers guide of the same. Or both.

I am setting up some servers for hosting and I want to configure them with just enough permissions. I have done this before where I modified the Medium trust and gave it database permissions etc but I only briefed over it.

I want to setup solid machines with the respective, common, permissions that people use. Is there maybe a resource that explains in detail what each trust level has by default? That way I could compare and go from there.

To start the security, I have made a rule on my machines that I only create dedicated application pools per site/user. I know Microsoft say that each website is virtually seperate, even in the shared application pool space, but I just don't trust it.

I also know I shouldn't run in Full Trust as I am opening up my server to all kinds of attacks.

I have a bit of knowledge on this but not enough so hopefully you lot can help me. I'm not wanting to be spoon fed what to do, I have no problem figuring it out, I just can't find the info to start with.

I appreciate your help.

Anthony

*I'm running:
Windows 2008 RC2 64 bit with IIS7.5 and a combination of 2.0/3.5 and 4.0 application pools.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strict best practice is "don't let anything do anything to anything" but that is counterproductive in general -- if you aren't taking HTTP requests, you don't have a working HTTP application server.

That said, your question is very general and very nebulous. The first key question is "what sort of hosting scenario is this?" For example, full trust isn't necessarily a bad thing in a dedicated scenario, or even a shared server between "friendly" apps that should trust each other. But it is bad in a hotel server situation where you've got random guests sharing space.

The second question is what sorts of apps are you hosting? You've got completely different frontages depending on what you are doing -- spammers don't try as hard as thieves. Spies try even harder.

Comment: I get what you mean. I suppose it is hard to answer. Well, it would be the "hotel" scheme as you put it, random clients. While .NET and PHP will be prominent, I haven't decided on other languages. As for applications they would be MySQL, MSSQL, MailEnable. I suppose what I am looking for is a list of permissions and their explanations. As per full trust, I was under the impression that this can allow any app to access the full file structure of the server where NTFS permissions are present?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx#paght000020_mediumtrustsummary for a good summary on trust restrictions. The big hole full trust opens is it could let an app break it's "root" and read or potentially modify any files it can find and has NTFS permissions for. Which could be real bad.

Comment: Ah. Now that is what I was after, I just couldn't Google it, I must of been using the wrong search terms. T'was lae when I lloked for it. Thanks for the info and the clarification on full trust. It is very appreciated.